# How to Store Object into Application Level Context in Grails

Tags: grails

I want to store HashMap Object like`HashMap<String,MyClass> contextHashMap = new HashMap<String,MyClass> ();` which will be accessible through out the application like as we store the object/variables in ApplicationContext of Struts.

So that I can Change or read the Data from this Variable whenever I need.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work about what you tried? What errors did you get? SO Isn't a code writing service. I suspect all you need is to setup a hashmap in your application context (e.g. `Resources.groovy`). I suggest you do some research and perhaps read the documentation about Grails and/or Spring (which is the core of Grails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn’t really clear what you need but one option would be to store the data in a singleton service and inject that service wherever it is needed.  That is a super simple solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply right now I'm doing the same using Singleton Class, but actually I want to store some information which will be accessible through out the application. Its like the variables in Application Context. And I just started with Grails, so don't know much about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a simple singleton Spring-bean of type `Map` (`ConcurrentHashMap`) and also inject into any Grails artefact:

resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
  contextHashMap( ConcurrentHashMap )
}
```

and inject:

```
class ExampleController {
  def contextHashMap
  … 
}
```